# Rails database ID number not being updated with destroy call

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite3-ruby

I'm new to rails so maybe the record id is not updated on destroy.

I used rails scaffold to generate my MVC for a products page. When I add an entry to my data base through my products/new page it adds an id number to the entry. When in a browser if I rollover the show/edit/destroy links on my index view it will give me a url link of localhost:3000/products/1. Now if I remove the entry by using the destroy link it removes the entry correctly, but now when I add another entry it shows the id as 2 not 1. Why does it remove the entry from the database but not reset the id back to 1.

This is for the build in server in rails app sqlite3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you would have to rake db:drop your database (which deletes it) and then rake db:migrate to create your tables again.

Comment: I just did rake db:schema:dump and it worked for me. Not sure what exactly that did. D

Answer (score 4):

Sqlite is using a sequence to determine the next available integer to use for the primary id.  Sequences don't "go back" even if you destroy the record with the latest one.  They keep incrementing.  Some databases will restart at zero once they reach a maximum, some will error.

Some databases tie a sequence to the table.  However in some, sequences are their own thing.  You could (if you wanted to) use a sequence to get unique ID's for several different tables.

Check sqlite's documentation for details...

Comment: Is there a way to reset it back or delete all and then migrate my table back in again.

Comment: Probably.  You'll need to read the Sqlite3 documentation to figure out how.  It varies from database to database.

Answer (score 1):

The command `rake db:schema:dump` Dumps the current environment’s schema to db/schema.rb.
To reset it back or delete all and migrate it again you should use the command `rake db:setup` Which runs `rake db:schema:load` and `rake db:seed`.

Some of the other important commands are;

`rake db:schema:load` This command loads the schema into the current environment’s database.

`rake db:schema:dump` This command dumps the current environment’s schema to `db/schema.rb`.

`rake db:setup` This command runs `rake db:schema:load` and `rake db:seed`.

`rake db:reset` This command runs `rake db:drop` and `rake db:setup`.

`rake db:migrate:reset` This command runs `rake db:drop` then `rake db:create` and `rake db:migrate`.